# Need where clause to find difference between 'today' and date_column > 10 days and < 15 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I am trying to figure out a where clause to find difference between 'today' and date_column > 10 days and < 15 days.

So far all I can think of is creating a variable for each? But I am not even sure if that's right. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datecol > dateadd(day, -15, convert(date, getdate())) and
      t.datecol < dateadd(day, -10, convert(date, getdate())) ;
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. Would you mind explaining the logic behind this a little bit? I'm still learning SQL at work.

Comment: This just subtracts a certain number of days from the current date and compares to your column.